# I need to install a secure package from git globally

Tags: ssh, root

I need to add install a package using npm globally.

The command to install it is
`npm i -g git+ssh://git@gitlab.companyname.io:1234/packagename/packagename.git`

To use this command I need to add something like this in my known hosts file

`gitlab.companyname.io,129.123.123.121 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 cant/show/you+the/key=` So I added that in ~/.ssh/known_hosts

However whenever I try to install it, my terminal says I don't have access. 
So I tried installing it using root.

The command did not run further but got blocked at something like

`[..................] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session somethignsomething`

How do I add the public key to the known hosts file and where do I add it so that I do am able to install it globally?

Comment: The line in `known_hosts` will be added automatically if you have never accessed that system using `ssh` before, so no need to do it manually. It would be helpful to see what actual error message you get when you try running your `npm` command.

Comment: @Kusalananda it shows nothing except for the blocked line I have provided.

Comment: You do mention that "my terminal says I don't have access". When does it say that if not when you run the `npm` command?  Also what is "somethignsomething"?

Comment: It's the session ID I did not remember it so I wrote something somethign